# Error using s3 bucket in jupyter notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, boto3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xqEz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGufj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb5Bu.png)
My s3 buckets are not showing using my log_data_files code
It keeps showing ParamValidationError no matter what tried
I used another yet the same error
What is my issue and how do I go about this?

Comment: Can you share how do you create the `boto` client?

Comment: What is the code producing the error?

Comment: i added it... used  s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                    region_name="us-east-1",
                    aws_access_key_id=KEY,
                    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET
                   )

Answer (score 0):

Python is case sensitive prefix is not equivalent to Prefix, try

`log_files=[filename. key for filename in bucket.objects.filter (Prefix='*)]`

Comment: it is still not working

Comment: ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "prefix", must be one of: Bucket, Delimiter, EncodingType, Marker, MaxKeys, Prefix, RequestPayer, ExpectedBucketOwner, OptionalObjectAttributes

Comment: that's the error code...what could be the issue?

Comment: Python is case sensitive prefix is not equivalent to Prefix